# How to reset layer style properties in layer styles window in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects, layer-style

Every time I go back to edit some layer effects for a new layer, there are weird presets, e.g. Screen or Overlay blend modes for some of the layer settings, and then the lighter gradient tone is always light yellow, not white.

I'm pretty sure this isn't to do with inheriting the layer effects from a previous layer (*could* be wrong), but regardless, how do I get these to restore to their defaults each time I'm editing layer effects?

Also, I'm quite sure yellow was never the default on the gradient bar, rather than white. How do I change this back?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Those actually sound like the defaults in Photoshop. I'd recommend setting up your own how you'd like. Scott's post shows a screenshot with the "Make Default" button. Set things up how you'd like, and click that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Layer Styles dialog has two buttons for each style option:

[image: styles]

Clicking these does exactly what they state.

I can't replicate an instance where the styles are anything but the default when applying styles to a new layer.